# ExecuteScalar() --- Input string error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a forum for online discussion and after creating a forum and i want users to write articles this is all i get

Input string was not in a correct format.

> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.FormatException: Input string was not in a
>   correct format.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> Line 43:             cmd.Parameters.Add("@MessageID",
>   System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "MessageID"); Line 44:
>   cmd.Parameters["@MessageID"].Value = e.Row.Cells[0].Text; Line 45:
>   string count = (cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
>
> **Source File:** c:\Users\A\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\WebSites\ODF\Default2.aspx.cs    Line: 45

And this is my code in the cs file

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\;Initial Catalog=ODF;Integrated Security=True");
        CN.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Comments] WHERE [MessageID] = @MessageID", CN);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MessageID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "MessageID");
        cmd.Parameters["@MessageID"].Value = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        string count = (cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        e.Row.Cells[4].Text = count;
        //for column2 postedby

        CN.Close();
    }
```

Please help out

Comment: Add the debugger and check the value of the `e.Row.Cells[0].Text`

Comment: Please help me out am new to applications how do i add the debugger ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [i keep getting input string is not a correct format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847533/i-keep-getting-input-string-is-not-a-correct-format)

Comment: Ok read it let me try iy and i still have loads of errors can u have a look at the system and show me how to change or improve it ??

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MessageID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "MessageID");
cmd.Parameters["@MessageID"].Value = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
```

To this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MessageID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
```